# F#: Creating new list from first element in nested list

Tags: f#

I've got an assigned problem where I have to create a function `firstColumn : lst : 'a list list -> 'a list`, which takes a list of lists and generates a new list using the first element from each nested list. For example, `firstColumn [[343;32];[11;75]]` would return a new table `[343;11]`.

So far I've tried using a loop to append each element's head (first element in the nested list) to the new list:

```ml
let firstColumn (lst : 'a list list) : 'a list =
  let newList = []
  for elm in lst do
    elm.Head :: newList
  newList
```

However, this results in warning `FS0020`, where the result of `elm.Head :: newList` is ignored, and `newList`'s inital empty table is returned.

Comment: Combining functional and imperative code in the same algorithm will often bite you, certainly when you're just starting out on your journey. The functional code `elm.Head :: newList` creates a new list, given lists are immutable, but you're not assigning it to anything. So even then you'd have to work with some mutable state. The functional approach would instead use the higher order function `List.map` and select the first element of each nested list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just misunderstood the syntax (not much of a misunderstanding, but just enough that you get the wrong result).
Look at this almost similar code, and spot the differences:

```
let firstColumn (lst : 'a list list) : 'a list =
  let mutable newList = []
  for elm in lst do
    newList <- elm.Head :: newList
  List.rev newList
```

Edit: I realize that Funk already answered almost the same thing, but I thought you might benefit from a more concrete code fix example.

Answer (score 1):

The implerative solution based on your example posted by Robert works fine. However, if you wanted to follow a functional style, then you can write the same thing using recursion and pattern matching:

```
let rec firstColumn lst = 
  match lst with 
  | (head::_) :: lst -> head :: (firstColumn lst)
  | _ -> []
```

The pattern `(head::_) :: lst` takes a list of lists, extracts the head of the first list and gives you remaining lists as `lst`, so you can then recursively process `lst` and append `head` to the front as the first column.